# Lenovo T450 laptop will not shut down after removing the battery

Tags: boot, shutdown

Ubuntu 20:04 keeps freezing, so I pulled out the battery and this fixed it.
Today I pulled out the battery and the program switched to the internal battery and did a dump. Now I cannot reboot, and my computer is frozen.

[image]

Comment: Strange that your laptop freezes. I have the same laptop and it's been running Ubuntu 20.04 for a long time, not freezing. Anyway, at that prompt, you can just hold down the power button to shutdown.

Comment: TNX Popey,  what lead up to the stack dump, I was trying to close a video on Twitter and got a message saying I was not authorized, sort of like a spammers captured my T450, so I tried to shut down the laptop but it would not shut down, so I pulled the battery off and that was when the stack dump started and my attached photo was what was on my screen,  So I left the T450 for several hours running on the internal battery and attempted shut  down by re installing the battery and holding down the function key while pressing the on/off switch.  Eventually the T450 rebooted